# odd double quotes in VBA interrogation to SQL database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i have this piece of VBA code inside an Access file, but i don't understand how the quotes and double quotes are placed. there are 3 double quotes and not 4, so i don't understand what it should represent. other than that, there is the ";" at the end and i don't know why. can someone help me?

```
If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT count(*) FROM Employees WHERE SerialNumber='" & Environ("Username") & "';").Fields(0) > 0 Then
    [Employee].Value = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Initials FROM Employees WHERE SerialNumber='" & Environ("Username") & "';").Fields(0)
Else
    [Employee].Value = Environ("Username")
End If
```

Comment: I can see 4 double quotes - before `SELECT`, before `& Environ` and two around the `';`.  The `;` isn't really needed though - hoping someone will tell me now why it's needed as I've been leaving it off for years.

Comment: Divide and conquer. 1. build the SQL string, 2. `Debug.Print` it, 3. Analyze / test. See [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570) --- The `;` is optional (or even obsolete).

Comment: @Andre don't think I could write SQL without Notepad++.  Saves a nicely formatted version of the query to - Access likes to muck up your formatting.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook what do you mean?

Comment: @Andre how can i test it? I don't know VBA. And what is that single quote before the semicolon?

Comment: `"SELECT count(*) FROM Emplpoyees WHERE SerialNumber='" & Environ("Username") & "';"`   you mis-spelled `Emplpoyees`

Comment: Basically, literal text within quotes and concatenate variables. The apostrophe delimits text field parameters. Date/time field would need # character, number field does not need delimiters.

Comment: Could use DLookup() instead of opening two recordsets. You want to pull initials if there is a record but if not then use USERNAME? Why not get employee's initials and create new record in Employees?

Comment: @June7 so are you saying to add the initials to the db if there is no record in the database? And how can I do that? I don't know vba and sql that well

Comment: Why have initials for some and USERNAME for others? Why not just USERNAME for all? Could somehow prompt user to input initials, either with InputBox or open a 'login' form. I do latter. Or you could assign initials. Of course, code will have to validate that initials do not already exist for another user.  Why initials at all? This is a new topic unrelated to original question and too broad. Lengthy discussion in comments is not appropriate. Attempt code and when you have specific issue, post question.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, Access query objects will add semi-colon if you don't. But you are correct, query will run. It is not needed for Recordset SQL statements. I think it may be needed in SQLServer stored procedures.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, not sure how you find Notepad++ helpful for formatting queries. It does not insert parentheses. Access is picky about parentheses for multiple JOIN clauses. True, it throws in more parens than WHERE clause needs. Use the QueryDesigner to get valid Access SQL. Create or modify in SQLView at your own risk.

Comment: @June7 I'm comfortable writing queries in SQLView and rarely use the Query Designer. So for me having the SQL saved in a text file (.SQL extension so I get the Notepad++ SQL highlighting) makes it easier to update them if needed.  Access will keep the formatting, but occasionally it opens in design view and when you switch back it usually takes out the line breaks, adds table names to fields that don't need it and puts multiple brackets around everything making it much harder to read.  But yes, agree that you create or modify in SQLView at your own risk.

Comment: Username is a number that identify who's logged to the computer, every employee as its own. when an employee open the access file and use it, automatically its initials will appear in the "employee" field, like a signature. that's all. how can i modify this specific code through SQLView?